# Monkey Patching Time.strftime not being picked up by Time class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8

I need to Monkey patch strftime in Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3 on Windows. In config\initializers I put this time_patch.rb file ([code below](http://mtjhax.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/ruby-1-8-strftime-works-differently-on-linux-and-windows/)) but it does not seem to be picking up:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32|mingw64|mswin32|mswin64/

  class Time
    alias_method :original_strftime, :strftime
    def strftime(fmt)
      hour12 = "%2d" % ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1)
      original_strftime(fmt.gsub(/%l/, hour12))
    end
  end

end
```

I renamed the method to `def blorping` and did `Time.methods` from the Rails console but did not see the new method.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: with 'def blorping . . .', try Time.now.methods

Comment: It is showing there... what did I do wrong; i.e. how do I get it added to the Time class?

Comment: strftime is an instance method, that's what you want

Comment: @klochner Thank you for your help. As it was not in answer form I found a few other of your answers that were useful for me and voted them up

Comment: no problem, i don't need the karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking the class methods when using `Time.methods`, so what you want is something like `Time.instance_methods` to be sure it's patched correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This exposed other issues I had with the environment/tests

Comment: You can also check `Time.instance_method(:strftime).source_location` in Ruby 1.9 to see where the method is defined. The internal one should return `nil`, a sign it's probably implemented in C in the Ruby VM, but yours would show the source location.

Comment: I do not think `source_location` is available to me in the Ruby 1.8.7 I am tied to.